Google calender event does not have the google meet link when creating the event
I'm trying to create a event using google calendar api, but when I create it passing
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet'
        },
        requestId: 'coding-calendar-demo'
      }
    }

the event is created but it has no google meet link
I'm using service account for the credentials
I'm also using node.js
Here is my full code:
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './meet-api-431818-d4ef4d9b2e75.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
});

function generateRandomString(length) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

async function createEvent() {
    const authClient = await auth.getClient();

    const event = {
        summary: 'Google I/O 2021',
        location: 'puta q pariu 1234',
        description: 'vai porra',
        start: {
            dateTime: '2024-08-12T09:00:00-07:00',
            timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        end: {
            dateTime: "2024-08-12T17:00:00-07:00",
            timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        },
        conferenceData: {
            createRequest: {
                requestId: generateRandomString(16),
                conferenceSolutionKey: {
                    type: "hangoutsMeet",
                },
            },
        },
    };

    try {
        const responsePromise = calendar.events.insert({
            auth: authClient,
            calendarId: 'primary',
            resource: event,
            conferenceDataVersion: 1,
            maxAttendees: 100,
        });

        const response = await responsePromise;

        console.log('Event created: %s', response.data.htmlLink);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating event:', error);
    }
}

createEvent();

I tried a lot of ways to make the event, none of them created a event with a google meet link
When I use the API test in the google workspace it runs perfectly, the event is created with a google meet link, but when I try the same thing using node it doesn't work.
